# Suggest Scientific papers collection with precision and recall for pre-judge query dataset

Tags: data-request

I'm working on a project for indexing scientific papers and I will need a free collection of papers with a pre-formed set of queries and his precision/recall values.

Anyone can tell me some suggestions?